# Recrusive Destructor for Binary Tree?

Tags: c++, function, recursion

How would you implement a destructor for a binary tree recursively?

A node has an element, a pointer to a left node, and a pointer to a right node.
  Also, when would you set the left and right node pointers to NULL?

Comment: The short answer is, *I wouldn't*. But if you had to, all the answers below will do it (at least as of this comment post time). Pick one that meets your tree layout.

Answer (score 2):

Destructors will recurse into members automatically. You shouldn't have to write a destructor manually hardly ever.

```
template<class T>
struct Node
{
    T data;
    std::unique_ptr<Node<T>> left, right;
};

template<class T>
struct BinaryTree
{
    std::unique_ptr<Node<T>> root;
};
```

Comment: …except that if the tree is very tall, the recursive destructor calls might cause a stack overflow.  To avoid that, you'd need to write a destructor that traverses the tree non-recursively.

Comment: Smart pointers will in fact recurse automatically, was each reference count devolves, but that property isn't necessarily desirable (with or without smart ptrs), in particular with large containers and especially with large *chains*. A chain of 100,000 elements sequentially recursing into smart pointer destruction will utterly blow out the activation stack unless it is done properly (i.e forcibly *avoid* the recursion).

Comment: The question specifically asked for a recursive destructor, though, and the implementation in this answer is the simplest way to accomplish that.

Comment: @WhozCraig If the binary tree is balanced, it will have a managable depth of a *most* 128 if using entire virtual RAM (64 bits for memory, times 2 if you're following the long fork (e.g. if all red nodes are present)).

I agree that relying on implicit recursive destructors is bad for a linked list, however.

Comment: @Wyzard Oh, I up-ticked the answer. It is in fact quite accurate and promotes smart pointer usage, which is nearly always a solid thing. I on commented on the general idea that recursing in the first place is not necessarily a tight idea. You're correct in assessment, thought, and I probably should have posted that comment in general rather than in response here. The answer definitely applies, and is worthy of up-tick (as are all the others, so far anyway).

Comment: @o11c I saw nothing about the tree being balanced, and considering *this* question, I sincerely doubt it is. My gripe about recursion solutions to blowing out a binary tree were admittedly misplaced (should be in general-comment), and in reality even smart pointers aren't the real reason behind that gripe (the same would happen with a simple `delete` left and right). Your answer is indeed accurate in response to the question posted, and thus was up-ticked. (and props for using `unique_ptr`, btw).

Answer (score 1):

Keeping o11c's answer in mind, if you choose not to use smart pointers and need to implement a destructor for nodes pointed to by bare pointers, use a post-order traversal.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Post-order

Answer (score 1):

> How would you implement a destructor for a binary tree recursively?

Like so:

```
~BinaryTreeNode()
{
    delete _left;
    delete _right;
}
```

> Also, when would you set the left and right node pointers to NULL?

Never in a destructor. You would do one or the other or maybe both in a node deletion method.